# Cannot run program "..../abc.exe": error=13, Permission denied

Tags: java, exec

I am trying to execute the following code:

```
       try 
        {     
            Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime() ;     
            Process p = rt.exec("/Users/abc/xyz.exe") ;     
            InputStream in = (InputStream) p.getInputStream() ;    
            OutputStream out = (OutputStream) p.getOutputStream();     
            InputStream err = (InputStream) p.getErrorStream() ; 
            System.out.println("in "+ in);
            System.out.println("out" + out);
            System.out.println("err" + err);
            //do whatever you want 

            p.destroy() ; 
        } 
        catch(Exception e) 
        {
         /*handle exception*/
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new Exception("Error " + e.getMessage(), e.getCause());
        }
```

and I am getting the following error :

```
Cannot run program "/Users/abc/xyz.exe": error=13, Permission denied
```

I checked if I have the necessary permissions and found this via terminal:

```
-rw-r--r--@ 1 username  staff  4016 Nov 22 23:12 /Users/abc/xyz.exe
```

Any suggestions on how to get this working?

Comment: Probably also requires `x` permission to execute.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You need to change permission of xyz.exe

```
chmod u+x /Users/abc/xyz.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

You didnt have execute permission in that file. You need to change the execute permission for that file.it only contains read and write. Please refer [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727008.aspx) to change permission

Comment: The resource you link to appears to be for Windows, but the OP seems to be on a U*x-ish platform. While some concept are similar, the MSND exposition is pretty horrible. Maybe try https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions#Traditional_Unix_permissions