# Error 13 Permission denied on gradle task

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-task

I'm trying to run the current task on `build.gradle` (Project) and receiving the following error:

> java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied.

```
task ("modifyStrings") {
    doLast{
        exec{
            workingDir '.'
            executable "./strings_script.sh"
        }
    }
}
```

If I try it like:

```
task modifyStrings(type: Exec) {
    doLast{
        workingDir '.'
        commandLine "./strings_script.sh"
    }
}
```

It give me back:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: execCommand == null!

What am I doing wrong?
(The script is in the root folder of the android project)

PS: In the same file there is another task, created a long time ago, that's why I'm putting my task here too if that matters.

```
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

The whole stack (I'm using a macOS Mojave):

```
10:53:01.800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
10:53:01.800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
10:53:01.800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
10:53:01.800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
10:53:01.800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':modifyStrings'.
10:53:01.800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > A problem occurred starting process 'command './strings_script.sh''
10:53:01.801 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
10:53:01.801 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
10:53:01.801 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  Run with --scan to get full insights.
10:53:01.801 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
10:53:01.801 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
10:53:01.801 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':modifyStrings'.
10:53:01.801 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$3.accept(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:148)
10:53:01.801 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$3.accept(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:145)
10:53:01.801 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:191)
10:53:01.801 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:138)
10:53:01.801 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:75)
10:53:01.801 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:62)
10:53:01.801 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:108)
10:53:01.801 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.java:67)
10:53:01.801 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
10:53:01.801 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:94)
10:53:01.801 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
10:53:01.801 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:95)
10:53:01.801 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
10:53:01.801 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
10:53:01.801 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
10:53:01.801 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:73)
10:53:01.802 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
10:53:01.802 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
10:53:01.802 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
10:53:01.802 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
10:53:01.802 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
10:53:01.802 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
10:53:01.802 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
10:53:01.802 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
10:53:01.802 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
10:53:01.802 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
10:53:01.802 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:43)
10:53:01.802 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:355)
10:53:01.802 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:343)
10:53:01.802 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
10:53:01.802 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
10:53:01.802 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:134)
10:53:01.802 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
10:53:01.802 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:202)
10:53:01.802 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:193)
10:53:01.802 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
10:53:01.803 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
10:53:01.803 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
10:53:01.803 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
10:53:01.803 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: A problem occurred starting process 'command './strings_script.sh''
10:53:01.803 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.execExceptionFor(DefaultExecHandle.java:232)
10:53:01.803 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.setEndStateInfo(DefaultExecHandle.java:209)
10:53:01.803 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.failed(DefaultExecHandle.java:356)
10:53:01.803 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.run(ExecHandleRunner.java:86)
10:53:01.803 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.CurrentBuildOperationPreservingRunnable.run(CurrentBuildOperationPreservingRunnable.java:42)
10:53:01.803 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   ... 3 more
10:53:01.803 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: net.rubygrapefruit.platform.NativeException: Could not start './strings_script.sh'
10:53:01.803 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.DefaultProcessLauncher.start(DefaultProcessLauncher.java:27)
10:53:01.803 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.WrapperProcessLauncher.start(WrapperProcessLauncher.java:36)
10:53:01.803 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.startProcess(ExecHandleRunner.java:97)
10:53:01.803 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.run(ExecHandleRunner.java:70)
10:53:01.803 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   ... 4 more
10:53:01.803 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "./strings_script.sh" (in directory "/Users/myUser/projects/NameOfProject"): error=13, Permission denied
10:53:01.803 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.DefaultProcessLauncher.start(DefaultProcessLauncher.java:25)
10:53:01.803 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   ... 7 more
10:53:01.803 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
10:53:01.803 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   ... 8 more
10:53:01.803 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
10:53:01.803 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
10:53:01.804 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
10:53:01.804 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] 
10:53:01.804 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED in 873ms
```

Comment: Error 13 is often SELinux - maybe check the logs?

Comment: Add more stacktrace information please.

Comment: Hey I found this, it might be similar to your case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27436972/cannot-run-program-abc-exe-error-13-permission-denied

Comment: Thanks, Wilson, I changed permission on the file and it didn't solve the issue. =/

Comment: well did you solve it?